# sort objects in alphabetical order with function javascript no button

Tags: javascript

```
  **Bu şekilde bir dizi nesnesi oluşturdum.Bunlara erişmek için function kullanmak istiyorum.Fakat for ve button kullanmadan erişemedim.İki tane fonksiyon kullandım birincisinde normal bir şekilde çıktı aldım.Fakat ikinci fonksiyonda sort ile sıralamasını istedim fakat olmadı.Nasıl bir yol izleyebilirim?**
```

this is code

> var list;
>                 list=[
>                        {name:"Elma",gram:700},
>                        {name:"Armut",gram:780},
>                        {name:"Kiraz",gram:750}
>                      ];

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what you want and clearly. I'm assuming this is what you're after based on the title:

```
list.sort(function(a,b) { return a.name.toLowerCase()>b.name.toLowerCase();})
```

Comment: listArray();
        function listArray() {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=
            list[0].name+"-"+list[0].gram+"<br>"+
            list[1].name+"-"+list[1].gram+"<br>"+
            list[2].name+"-"+list[2].gram+"<br>"+
            list[3].name+"-"+list[3].gram+"<br>"+
            ;
        }     bu durumda çalışıyor.Yeni bir fonksiton açıp list.sort() method'u eklediğimde çalışmıyor.İlk fonksiyon çalışıyor ikicisi çalışmıyor.